# custom credential provider plugin

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

To retrieve the credentials (aws_access_key, aws_secret_access_key, aws_session_token) to access AWS services via the cli, we have to call a custom service first to get our temporary credentials. If the credentials have expired we need to retrieve new credentials.

Using boto it is possible to write a custom credential provider by extending `boto.provider.Provider`. Is something similar possible to extend the aws cli?

Although not documented, I know it is possible to write plugins for the aws cli. Can I leverage this functionality to implement my own credential retriever?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to create an object that implements the `CredentialProvider` [class in botocore](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/credentials.py#L219).

Once that's created you can have the CLI add it to the set of credential providers to check.

If you want an example of this, the AssumeRole credential provider is written as an "internal" plugin in the CLI.  You'd need to do [something similar](https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/blob/develop/awscli/customizations/assumerole.py#L33) to this.  You'll get the `credential_provider` component from the session and then inject yours into the chain.  You might want to take a look at the default set of [providers](https://github.com/boto/botocore/blob/develop/botocore/credentials.py#L50) and decide where your custom credential provider should be placed.

Comment: Is it possible to declare default plugins at the cli installation/global level or does each user have to define the plugins in the ~/.aws/config?

Comment: I have posted sample code here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62032705/2132930