# Where can I find the documentation for writing custom AWS credential provider using boto3?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I am looking to create a python process to refresh temporary AWS credentials (valid for 30 mins) at runtime to ensure my code can run continuously for more than 30 mins.

What is RefreshableCredentials and how do I use it?

Comment: Where can I find information of writing a custom credential provider if I want to implement the solution discussed here: https://github.com/boto/boto3/issues/619

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After a lot of poking around, I finally came to conclusion that the botocore and boto3 classes are not documented.

I looked at the source code and have implemented a solution that works for my use case. Posting it here for others to refer.

```
class AWSCredsRefresh:

    def run(self):
        session = get_session()
        cred_provider = session.get_component('credential_provider')

        cred_provider.insert_before('env', CustomCredentialProvider())

        boto3_session = Session(botocore_session=session)
        #Perform AWS operations with boto3_session

class CustomCredentialProvider(CredentialProvider):
    CANONICAL_NAME = "custom-creds"

    def __init__(self):


    def load(self):
        #These creds will be automatically refreshed using the _refreh method if the current creds are going to expire in 15 mins or less
        creds = DeferredRefreshableCredentials(refresh_using=self._refresh, method="sts-assume-role",)
        return creds

    def _refresh(self):
        #Refresh your AWS creds using custom process
        response = self._custom_aws_cred_refresh()
        credentials = {
            "access_key": response.get("AccessKeyId"),
            "secret_key": response.get("SecretAccessKey"),
            "token": response.get("SessionToken"),
            "expiry_time": response.get("Expiration").isoformat(),
        }
        return credentials

    def _custom_aws_cred_refresh(self):
        #Your custom AWS cred refresh code
        return response


if __name__ == '__main__':
    obj = AWSCredsRefresh()
    obj.run()
```

Answer (score 2):

Full AWS boto3 documentation: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/index.html

Credentials documentation: https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html

RefreshableCredentials is a botocore class acting like a container for credentials needed to authenticate requests, and it can automatically refresh the credentials

This is a great guide on how to use it: https://dev.to/li_chastina/auto-refresh-aws-tokens-using-iam-role-and-boto3-2cjf

Comment: I have already check the official documentation. It does not provide any information on the CredentialProvider OR RefreshableCredentials.

I have checked this blog as well. I am looking for some 'official' documentation.